# Query returning same results even though the ID changes

Tags: query, meta-query

```
$topics = query_posts( array( 
      'post_type' => 'topics', 
      'post_status' => 'publish', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
      'meta_query' => array(
             'key' => 'forum_category', 
             'value' => $forum_id, 
             'compare'   => '=' 
             ) 
      ) 
 );
```

Doesn't seem to make a difference to this query what you set $forum_id to, it just loads all topics for all forum_category inputs... Any ideas what could cause this?

Just to be clear, this is a function being called in the loop, so where the function is being called $forum_id is set by get_the_id()

Comment: use `var_dump(get_the_id())` its the number different?

Comment: Yes, tested that and the number is different.

Comment: Have you tried using different operators? Such as `LIKE` or `IN`. By the way, you should use `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()`.

Comment: Why would I use WP_Query?

Comment: `query_posts` will override the main query. Have a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/94498).

Comment: Ah, I thought that you only used WP_Query with the main loop because I understood it overrides the main query. I guess I miss understood. So should I use a while loop here too, like the main loop?

Comment: Yes, you should always use your custom written loop in such cases. [this](https://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/) articles explains the issue further.

Comment: Okay, just to be sure though: the function that is being called is from a plugin and not in the main loop but a custom loop.

Comment: I have changed all the queries in the function to use WP_Query, I get the same error, the query posted in my question still returns all results the same, no matter what the ID is set to.

Comment: Avoid `query_posts`, in favor of `WP_Query`, but better yet, don't replace the main query with a second, and instead modify it with the `pre_get_posts` filter, avoiding pagination, overriding, and slowness/performance problems. Also keep in mind that queries with `meta_query` are super expensive/slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the query to:

```
 $topics = query_posts( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'topics',
                'meta_query'  => array( 
                    array( 
                        'key' => 'forum_category', 
                        'value' => $forum_id 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        );
```

fixed it, I guess the meta query had to be in a double array? I can't see any difference apart from that...

Comment: Yes, `meta_query` accepts those query arguments in an array - to pass then in directly you can use `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_type` and `meta_compare` instead of `array(key, value, type, compare)`. See examples in the [WP_Query Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Answer (score 2):

**You can pass your meta query into query_posts or (the preferable) WP_Query in 2 ways:**

1. An array using the array keys `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_type` and `meta_compare`
2. An array of arrays using the array keys `key`, `value`, `type` and `compare`

In your question, you were trying to use a mix of the two, and that's why it wasn't working.

**1. An array using the array keys `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_type` and `meta_compare`**

This is the way you were trying to do it in your question, but the meta_query should have been using the following array keys:

```
$args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'topics', 
      'post_status' => 'publish', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
      'meta_query' => array(
             'meta_key' => 'forum_category', 
             'meta_value' => $forum_id, 
             'meta_compare'   => '=' 
             ) 
      ) 
 );
```

**2. An array of arrays using the array keys `key`, `value`, `type` and `compare`**

From the [Codex for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

> **Important Note**: meta_query takes an **array** of meta query arguments **arrays** (it takes an array of arrays) - you can see this in the examples below. This construct allows you to query multiple metadatas by using the **relation** parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the meta queries.

```
$args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'topics', 
      'post_status' => 'publish', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
      'meta_query' => array(
          array(
             'key' => 'forum_category', 
             'value' => $forum_id, 
             'compare'   => '=' 
             ) 
          )
      ) 
 );
```

The advantage of using this way is that you can add multiple meta_queries to refine the results, for example you could get all posts where both forum_category = $forum_id AND forum_moderator = $moderator_name

```
$args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'topics', 
      'post_status' => 'publish', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
      'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',  // this could also be "OR"
          array(
             'key' => 'forum_category', 
             'value' => $forum_id, 
             'compare'   => '=' 
             ),
          array(
            'key'     => 'forum_moderator',
            'value'   => $moderator_name,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
          )
      ) 
 );
```

**Ref**: See the [Codex for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for more information and examples.

***Note***: I realise you found an answer, but I thought the additional information and alternative usage might be helpful - even if not to you, then to other users searching with a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was for the function I was writing I couldn't do it inside the usual loops so I couldn't figure a decent way around using the method I went with.

Comment: @lukgoh No problem. And it turns out that all you'd wrong was the array key names! That's why I thought I'd post a full answer here, just in case anyone else runs into the same problem - its so simple to get them mixed up :)